# show dialog without FragmentActivty

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-support-library

This may be rather obvious, but I cannot get it.
I am trying to use the [suggested way of creating dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html), by extending `DialogFragment`. Now, the problem is, I don't know how to invoke it. Documentation states:

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new FireMissilesDialogFragment();
newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "missiles");
```

but my Activity does not extend FragmentActivity (and due to the design of my application, it cannot extend it), so `getSupportFragmentManager()` cannot be invoked.

Any workaround for this? 
I would like to skip the deprecated way of creating a dialog.

Comment: If your app is designed for API levels >= 11 you could use the native fragments(with `getFragmentManager()`). Otherwise you don't have any options.

Comment: Hi @Maggie download the support library

Comment: I am using the support library as I need to support the older versions.

Comment: Then you need to extend FragmentActivity or use Dialog rather DialogFragment

Comment: sorry for silly question but just for confirmation are you extending DialogFragment or any other class ? Also in that class you want to get support for FragmentManager right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no.

The [FragmentActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) (and it's variants) are the ones that support the FragmentManager and the Fragments.

Common solutions to what you might believe "and due to the design of my application, it cannot extend it"

- If you're using a ListActivity, just put a list in your layout.
- If you're using a MapActivity, switch to the new map API.
- If you're using a TabActivity, that's deprecated, you should use Fragments.

Comment: Everything you stated is correct, and although it does not solve my problem, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can create a class that extend DialogFragment and invoke it like this:

```
_dialogFiltre = FragmentDialog.newInstance(R.string.tle_dialog_filter, this);
                _dialogFiltre.setValidDialogListener(this);
                _dialogFiltre.setCancelable(false);
                _dialogFiltre.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
```

The method new instance :

```
public static DialogFilter newInstance(int title, Context context) {

    FragmentDialog dialog = new FragmentDialog();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("title", title);
    dialog.setArguments(args);
    dialog._context = context;
    return dialog;
}
```

If you are not in a FragmentActivity i don't see any solution. Why does your application design does not let you use FragmentActivity ?

Comment: Because I have sort of a library project and each activity in my project extends base activity from that library project. And since that library project is used in 20 other applications in my company, it is not easy making changes to it, without risking breaking something else. I have given quite a lot of thought about this design issue, but haven't been able to come up with a good enough solution.

Comment: Oh i see. No easy solutions :/ So you can't create a BaseFragmentActivity just for cases as this one ? (in addition to the BaseActivity)

Comment: Hi @Maggie I know you already accepted my answer, but just an extra regarding what you said on this library. The company should really really look into upgrading this library because more and more functionality will not be available without extending FragmentActivity. For example, the maps V2, the loaders, the dialogs, tablets, etc.

Comment: @Budius I completely agree with you, but unfortunately that decision is not mine to make

Answer (score -1):

well you can directly invoke `getSupportFragmentManager();` on `FragmentActivity` but not on `Fragment` itself. So to invoke `getSupportFragmentManager();` what you can do is first get `FragmentActivity` and on that call `getSupportFragmentManager();`. So as you're getting `FragmentActivity`, you can call this function like:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

here `getActivity()` returns `FragmentActivity` associated with your `Fragment`.

what you have done is
1. First you have created instance of your custom `DialogFragment` class.
2. you're showing that dialog.

Now as you've already created an instance of custom `DialogFragment` why not use that to retrieve support for fragment manager. So what you can do is:

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new FireMissilesDialogFragment();
newFragment.show(newFragment.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "missiles");
```

what this will do is you're getting `FragmentActivity` associated with `newFragment` and on that `FragmentActivity` you're calling `getSupportFragmentManager();`.

Unfortunately I have not tested it but this might work. Try it and let us know.

Comment: No, it does not work. I think it is against all logic that something like this might even work. My activity does not extend FragmentActivity, as I have stated, so getSupportFragmentManager returns null. Sorry for the downwote, but I just had to eliminate the further misleading.